# How do I programmatically scroll down on WKWebView scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, wkwebview

I have a collectionView and in each cell I have a WKWebView loading html from a local file.
I want to scroll down to a specific offset from code.

I have tried using:

`self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y = offSet`

and

`self.webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: offSet), animated: false)`

with and without 
`layoutIfNeeded()`

but with no success.

The `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {}`
Does get called and the contentOffset.y does increase, but the scroll view does not move at all.

Comment: Maybe answer in this topic will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659208/how-to-programmatically-scroll-ios-wkwebview-swift-4. Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53542236/9048325

Comment: That's basically what I have tried. I might have an issue somewhere because my scrollview does not move no matter what value I try to offSet it by, not sure why.